# Android losing websocket connection in foreground service

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, foreground-service

I am using a websocket connection to my server to receive/send specific messages.
There messages also comes with a Notification.

Everything works fine when the connection is made. The Push Notification shows up when i send a message from the server to the App and everything works fine, but when i try it again after 30 minutes or longer and send a Message from my server to the App nothing happens.
From what i can see in the logs both the App and the server socket connection is not disconnected :/ .

Is there a reason why this happening?

Do I have to ping every minute to the server to keep the connection up and running?

This is the code that I am using to start the Service.

MainActivity

```
...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val myServiceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundSocket::class.java)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, myServiceIntent)
    }
...
```

ForegroundSocket

```
...
    // Binder given to clients (notice class declaration below)
    private var notification: Notification? = null
    private val mBinder: MyBinder = MyBinder()

    // Channel ID for notification
    val CHANNEL_ID = "Random number notification"

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder. The Binder object is responsible for returning an instance
     * of "MyService" to the client.
     */
    inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
        // Return this instance of MyService so clients can call public methods
        val service: ForegroundSocket
            get() =// Return this instance of MyService so clients can call public methods
                this@ForegroundSocket
    }

    /**
     * This is how the client gets the IBinder object from the service. It's retrieve by the "ServiceConnection"
     * which you'll see later.
     */
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return mBinder
    }

    /**
     * Called when service is created So  we will do our work here
     */
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("MyBoundService", "onCreate called")
        startNotification()
    }

    /**
     * Used for creating and starting notification
     * whenever we start our Bound service
     */
    private fun startNotification() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "My Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )

        (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
            channel
        )
        notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_lock_outline)
            .setTicker("Ticker text")
            .setContentTitle("A service is running in the background")
            .setContentText("Generating random number")
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
    }

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know where the Binder base class comes from but a websocket implementation should provide onClose

```
override fun onClose(code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClose")
    unsubscribe()
}
```

If onClose is unexpected(not closed by client), then you should try to reconnect.

Answer (score -2):

In this way you use bound services and inbound services, when activity is destroyed, the services are destroyed, too.
So unbounded these services by returning null on bind.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what the OP can do to fix their problem.